# HTML Select populated on mouse down doesn't expand

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a `select` as such: `<select id="location" onmousedown="FileTransferInCombo(this)"></select>`.

The idea is to populate it when the user clicks it, with this method:

```
function FileTransferInCombo(combo)
{
    var $combo = $(combo);
    var options_count = $combo.find('option').length;

    if (options_count == 0)
    {
        $.getJSON("AJAXTransferInEdit.aspx", { action: 'combo' }, function (j)
        {
            var options = LoadCombo(j);

            $combo.html(options);
            //$combo.empty().append(options);
        });
    }
}
```

`LoadCombo(j)` simply returns a `string` with the `options` as such: `<option value="1">Blue</option><option value="2">Red</option>`.

This works fine, but I'd like the `select` to expand normally as if nothing was done on mouse down. Just the normal behaviour.

I tried both `$combo.html(options);` and `$combo.empty().append(options);`, looked for answers on SO but found nothing relevant. Thought about forcing it to expand, but it looks like you can't call `.click()` on a `select` either.

Is there a way to "block" the `onmousedown` event and let it finish after my AJAX call has done the work?

Comment: Your issue is because you fill the content on `mousedown`. The AJAX request then completes some time after the event occurred, hence the options are not shown. It would make far more sense to pre-populate the options before the element is clicked on.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That's what we usually do. But in this case, the combo is a column of a table, so if the table has 50 rows, there are 50 combos to pre-populate. Our users aren't likely to use these combos anyway, hence the need to populate them one by one only when needed.

Comment: Ok, I see the issue. Maybe you could use some kind of lazy-loading instead to only populate the fields when they're visible on the screen?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan What do you mean with lazy-loading? Not sure how to implement it.

Comment: why not binding `.change` to the `select` instead of `onmousedown`?

Comment: @ShiranDror The select is empty by default, until the user clicks it. Can't use the `change` event as there would be nothing to change.